# How to show array count in label which is connected to another viewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How do I show the number of items in the array representing my tableView on another ViewController? I need the information even before the second viewController even launched for the first time. Or do I have to get the information directly from my Database because that's where the array is coming from?

I thought it would work like this:

```
counterLbl.text = SecondViewController[myArray.count]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to set a label on another view controller. You should treat a view controller's views as private.

You should give the view controller a count property and set it when the count changes. Then in the view controller's viewWillAppear method it can use the count to update the label.

Your comment "I need the information even before the second viewController even launched for the first time" is puzzling however.

Do you have a shared data model of some sort? It sounds like both view controllers should be querying a model object to get their information rather than trying to pass info between view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, If the array is shared between two view controllers then it's better you query and get the array list in `FirstViewController` itself.

Once you have the array then,

In `FirstViewController`,

```
var dbArray: [Any] = [] //Any can be your array data type
dbArray = // populate this array from db query

counterLbl.text = "\(dbArray.count)"
```

Then you can pass the same array to `SecondViewController`,

```
let secondVC = SecondViewController()
secondVC.dbArr = dbArray // dbArr is a variable in SecondViewController
```

You can use this `dbArr` in `SecondViewController` to populate the tableView.

Comment: isn't it the wrong way around? Because the Label is in the first viewController

Comment: the tableView is in which view controller ? first or second

Comment: the second view controller

Answer (score 1):

1)create a variable in AppDelegate class  which is indicates the array count

```
int count;
```

then get the array count in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, later assign array objects count to that variable

```
_count =  arrObjects.Count;
```

so, where ever you want to show that count you can use that count variable,(for accessing that variable you have to create shared object for that AppDelegate class)

```
AppDelegate * app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

counterLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",app.count];
```

In Swift....

1)create a variable in AppDelegate class  which is indicates the array count

```
var count = 0
```

then get the array count in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, later assign array objects count to that variable

```
count =  arrObjects.Count
```

so, where ever you want to show that count you can use that count variable,(for accessing that variable you have to create shared object for that AppDelegate class)

```
let appDelegateRef = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

counterLbl.text = "\(appDelegateRef.count)"
```